# Arch Linux, Cinnamon not responsive

Tags: cinnamon, desktop-environment

After doing some update/configuration changes.
As I remember it correctly I was updated all the drivers, even though I don't know which is the correct / used one. Cinnamon got stuck. My original desktop environment was XFCE, and then I installed Cinnamon and lightDM.

###### inxi -G :

```
    Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] driver: radeon v: kernel
  Device-2: AMD Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 M430 Radeon
    520 Mobile]
    driver: radeon v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: radeon
    unloaded: modesetting gpu: radeon resolution: 1: 1600x900~60Hz
    2: 1366x768~60Hz
  Message: Unable to show GL data. Required tool glxinfo missing.
```

The tty is silent, it just says "starting arch, recovering journal, clean".

The UI just showing my wallpaper without any controls or buttons. The following do not work from the UI:

- linux key to show menu.
- spawning terminal with alt + T (but this one already configured).
- the panel is not showing (expected spawn htop-ui from here).

any tips / hack?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us about your hardware, especially the graphics card and the driver you use with it (you can get this with `inxi -G`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wanna be detective? read the [journal](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Journal#Filtering_output):

`# journalctl --since "20 min ago"`

I am not a hacker, but try restarting cinnamon from the second tty:

`$ export DISPLAY=:0; cinnamon --replace &`

Magically, my case solved by: doing login via the default Xfce login screen, and reboot. Login via lightdm and cinnamon start normally.

Comment: And? Does this work?

Comment: solved now, even I don't know why.